# How can I set up a shortcut key for changing selected text to a preferred font in Libreoffice?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

How can I set up a shortcut key for changing selected text to a preferred font in Libreoffice?

Preferred font in my case is Segoe Print

I have come this far:

Tools → Customise → Keyboard
selected my hotkey for assignment (here Alt+x)
then selected Format → Font Name

Pressing Alt+x now, after selecting a portion of text makes me do extra steps which I am hoping can be done with the original shortcut.

That is here I have to do Ctrl+A to select Times New Roman, then press Del key to delete it, then type Segoe Print, then press Enter. How can I automate this? Probably via another shortcut key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a character/paragraph style. Here are some tutorials:

- http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/384994-create-custom-styles-and-formatting-in-libreoffice-writer
- Videos 26, 29, and 30 in this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aza63cQilrc&index=30&list=PL94682FC0D2ADF410

Comment: I created a custom style with Segio Print as the font, but it does not persist when I open a different document?